# Background image zooming in on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this but can't seem to solve it. The main background image [here](http://www.katieclarkcounselling.co.uk/) zooms in massively on iPhone. This is my background image code:

```
.home-featured {
    background-image: url(/Roombg2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

I'm not sure if other CSS for home-featured is causing any problems:

```
.home-featured .wrap {
    margin-top: -160px;
    max-width: 782px;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-featured .home-widgets-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 200px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated - I'm completely lost on this!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to configure the meta viewport tag. In the iphone the viewport behaves a little different.

Check this: [Configuring the viewport](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)